# json and knockout

Tags: ajax, json, knockout.js

i have a table that is "supposed" to be binded with the result of a json but it is not working, what could be the errors?

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Id
        </th>
        <th>
            Number
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Password
        </th>
        <th>
            Role
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: model.Employees">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: EmployeeId"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: EmployeeNumber"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: EmployeeName"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: EmployeePassword"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: EmployeeRole"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

my knockout script for that is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = {};
    var data = $.getJSON("Employees.json", function (data) {
        viewModel= ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    }
    );
});
</script>
```

here is my sample returned json data:

```
 {"Employees":[{"EmployeeId":1,"EmployeeName":X","EmployeeNumber":"1","EmployeePassword":"x","EmployeeRole":"User"},{"EmployeeId":10,"EmployeeName":"S","EmployeeNumber":"21","EmployeePassword":"s","EmployeeRole":"Admin"}]}
```

Comment: Please add this span at the top and post what it shows: `<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></span>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [binding json data using knockout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842900/binding-json-data-using-knockout)

Comment: now using angular js.. ahaha! so long knockout... ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open up your browser's error console I bet you're seeing something like this:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError:
>   Employees is not defined; Bindings value: foreach: Employees

`Employees` is not defined on `viewModel`. It is, however, defined on `viewModel.model`. Things should work if you either:

1. `data-bind` the foreach on `model.Employees` instead:

   ```
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: model.Employees">
   ```

   **Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ze2Zs/
2. Assign the results of your AJAX request directly to `viewModel` instead of `viewModel.model`:

   ```
   viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
   ```

   **Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/wHXeP/

Also as a side note there's no need to assign `var data = $.getJSON(...)` as the response is handled by the callback function:

```
var viewModel = {};
$.getJSON("Employees.json", function (data) {
    viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Comment: i see in your fiddle that viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data); and 
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel); is outside the var data ={}... but mine is inside, is that ok?

Comment: I didn't notice that when I first looked at the question. You should probably get rid of the `var data` outside the AJAX request, but the apply bindings and viewModel code does belong inside of the callback function. Mine is slightly different because I'm not making an AJAX request.

Comment: you're right, it is saying that error... i edited my code above, however, it is still not working and that error keeps showing up

Comment: the returned json data is actually an array, i think that is the problem

Comment: okay! i modified it:  var trueData = JSON.stringify(data);
            viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJSON(trueData);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

it works now! :)